# Biblatex add comma after journal issue before year

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

I just started to work with Biblatex and I'm struggling to figure out how to add a comma for articles after the issue number and before the year.

This is how my footnote citation looks like:

[image: This is how my footnote citation looks like:]

And that's how it's supposed to look:

[image: And that's how it's supposed to look:]

Here is my MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents}{my-bib.bib} 
 @article{Lubbers.2002,
 author = {Lubbers, Marcel and Gijsberts, M{\'e}rove and Scheepers, Peer},
 year = {2002},
 title = {{E}xtreme {R}ight-{W}ing {V}oting in {W}estern {E}urope},
 pages = {345--378},
 volume = {41},
 number = {3},
 issn = {03044130},
 journal = {European Journal of Political Research}
 }
 \end{filecontents}

 \documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
 \usepackage[margin= 1in]{geometry}
 \usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=verbose-trad3, isbn=false, doi=false, firstinits=true, citepages=suppress]{biblatex} 
\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}

% Commas as separators
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

\usepackage{xpatch}
% No dot before number of articles
\xpatchbibmacro{volume+number+eid}{%
  \setunit*{\adddot}%
}{%
}{}{}
% Number of articles in parentheses
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

% Comma before and after journal volume
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}% NEW
  \printfield{volume}%
%  \setunit*{\adddot}% DELETED
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}% NEW
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}

% Prefixes for journal volume and number
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\bibstring{volume}~#1}% volume of a journal
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\bibstring{number}~#1}% number of a journal

% Comma before date; date not in parentheses
\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}% NEW
%  \printtext[parens]{% DELETED
    \iffieldundef{issue}
      {\usebibmacro{date}}
      {\printfield{issue}%
       \setunit*{\addspace}%
%       \usebibmacro{date}}}% DELETED
       \usebibmacro{date}}% NEW
  \newunit}


\bibliography{my-bib}  
\begin{document}
Test\autocite{Lubbers.2002}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I wish to add a comma after the issue number for articles. 
Does anybody know a solution to this?

Comment: what about changing `\setunit*{\addspace}` to `\setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you are: patching `journal+issuetitle`:

```
\begin{filecontents}{my-bib.bib}
 @article{Lubbers.2002,
 author = {Lubbers, Marcel and Gijsberts, M{\'e}rove and Scheepers, Peer},
 year = {2002},
 title = {{E}xtreme {R}ight-{W}ing {V}oting in {W}estern {E}urope},
 pages = {345--378},
 volume = {41},
 number = {3},
 issn = {03044130},
 journal = {European Journal of Political Research}
 }
 \end{filecontents}

 \documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
 \usepackage[margin= 1in]{geometry}
 \usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=verbose-trad3, isbn=false, doi=false, firstinits=true, citepages=suppress]{biblatex}
\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}

% Commas as separators
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

\usepackage{xpatch}
% Comma before issue + date
\xpatchbibmacro{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}}%
{\setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}}%
{}{}

% No dot before number of articles
\xpatchbibmacro{volume+number+eid}{%
  \setunit*{\adddot}%
}{%
}{}{}
% Number of articles in parentheses
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

% Comma before and after journal volume
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}% NEW
  \printfield{volume}%
% \setunit*{\adddot}% DELETED
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}% NEW
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}

% Prefixes for journal volume and number
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\bibstring{volume}~#1}% volume of a journal
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\bibstring{number}~#1}% number of a journal

% Comma before date; date not in parentheses
\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}% NEW
% \printtext[parens]{% DELETED
    \iffieldundef{issue}
      {\usebibmacro{date}}
      {\printfield{issue}%
       \setunit*{\addspace}%
% \usebibmacro{date}}}% DELETED
       \usebibmacro{date}}% NEW
  \newunit}

\bibliography{my-bib}
\begin{document}

\vspace*{6in}
Test\autocite{Lubbers.2002}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]